# What's the difference between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:36232?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

I do not understand what these different EPSG's mean, even though they are both under WGS84.

The way the latitude and longitude values displayed are different in both the cases when I try to change the projections from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:36232  using pyproj in Python.

Can you clarify if the units of latitude and longitude values differ?

Comment: Did you think of `EPSG 32632 WGS84 UTM zone 32N`? That has meters as units, while EPSG:4326 works in degrees.

Answer (score 5):

As AndreJ assumed, I'm believe you meant EPSG::32632, WGS 1984 / UTM Zone 32 North. It's a projected coordinate reference system and its unit of measure is the meter, not decimal degrees. If your lat/lon coordinates fall within that zone, the values should range between:

```
Easting: 200 km to 800 km  
Northing: 0 km to 10000 km
```

Answer (score 0):

EPSG 36232 is not a valid EPSG code:
http://epsg.io/?q=36232

Why not just use EPSG:4326 if you want WGS 84.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure if 'EPSG:36232' exists, but if does it is most likely to produce incorrect outputs. I'd advice you to use 'ESPG:4326' and transform it to 'EPSG:3857'.

Comment: There isn't any information in the question to determine whether EPSG::3857 is an appropriate CRS to use.